# Do I need to Update to webdriver from webdriver backed selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have created my tests using Webdriver backed selenium. So I use selenium session variable to click(), type(), select, etc. the web page elements and my tests are working fine.

I use xpath for locating elements, most of the time.

Do I need to update to selenium Webdriver completely?

Please can anyone give suggestions.

Comment: You haven't made yourself clear at all. You should always try to keep uptodate with any third party packages and libraries.

Comment: To make my question clear, am using the following lines in my code:

Comment: `driver = new FirefoxDriver();DefaultSelenium selenium = new **WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);selenium.type(<locator>, "string");` My question is, **webDriverBackedSelenium, which I have used, will be supported in the future also or should I update to **Webdriver** code like below: `driver.get("url"); driver.findElement(By.id("locatorid").sendKeys("string");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you've cleared up your question, is the answer is that you should use the WebDriver if you can.

WebDriverBackedSelenium is only there to allow you to use the old v1 API with the WebDriver API.

I cannot comment on if it's going to be removed at some point (as I'm not a Selenium committer) but you should move to WebDriver when you can.

If there are methods you want to use, port them over.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I understand your question, for my project I use maven build manager.
So I add selenium dependecy to POM.xml file and maven would automatically suggest to import all the actual data needed for project (repository indices update).
add such dependency in your POM.xml project file:

```
• <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.
selenium</groupId> <artifactId>selenium-
java</artifactId> <version>2.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In that way I keep my selenium driver up to date. If the version becomes newer, you simply change version in your pom xml and that's it )
Maven dependecy screen [image: screen]